# How to retrieve a Pokémon Go account when you log in and it tells you to start all over again

Tags: pokemon-go

Hi so I have an account and so does my sister.I logged out to play for her but when I tried to log back in it made me start from scratch (choose character, a starter, and a name) Is there a way I can get my account back it was level 10 so I don't want to restart 
IT IS NOT A REPETITION OF [Is it possible to log back into a Pokemon Go account?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273370/is-it-possible-to-log-back-into-a-pokemon-go-account)

It is not a repetition because that is asking if you can log back in to play and the answer is yes but I logged in and I had to restart from zero so I'm asking how to get my level 10 account back

Comment: Please help me and don't just mark it a duplicate or leave a URL to the question

Comment: It's a differen question Dragonrage because I did everything the same and it made me restart from scratch the other one is just a question of how to log back in mine is I do and I have to start from scratch

Comment: Unfortunately, this question has already been asked.  We do our best to ensure that the same questions are all linked to the same one, so that anyone with the same issue can get the same help.

Comment: Just saying it's not a duplicate doesn't make it so.  If it's not a duplicate, edit the question to tell us *how* it's not asking the same thing.  Make it clearer.

Comment: NOT A DUPLICATE OF http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273370/is-it-possible-to-log-back-into-a-pokemon-go-account

Comment: Again, **tell us how it's not**.  You can't just say it's not and expect us to not close it.  It's up to you to clarify how it's not.

Comment: It is not a repetition because that is asking if you can log back in to play and the answer is yes but I logged in and I had to restart from zero so I'm asking how to get my level 10 account back

Comment: @FelipeValencia It also says "If these options aren't enough, you can probably find a relevant topic or email address to contact Pokemon Go support on their website. https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us "

Comment: Tried it 5 times always get the same sensored message

Comment: Always says they can't respond any question don't even read the request you get the message instantly after you send the request

Comment: Did your sister use a Trainer Club account? I remember reading another question that would indicate that using a Trainer Club account would wipe a previously used Google-accounts progress. However, I can't find it anymore and I don't think there was any known solution. If the Niantic isn't responding either (theis support must be overworked), I think you may be out of luck. See Kez's answer here.

Comment: It's was a gmail account to be more specific it was  my second gmail which I let her use it as she doesn't have her own to play the game and I hope I get it back because I did a lot of walking to get to level ten

Comment: Try explaining a bit more. Are you using the same account? I.e, did you log into a Google account, and then try and log in to a different account (another Google account, or a Trainer Club account for example)?

Comment: Yes I am using the same google account with Pokémon Go(1.0.2) and I logged out into another account and when I tried to go back in to my normal gmail account it made me restart (choose a character, starter, and a name)

Comment: Now it is 1.0.3

Answer (score 0):

If it's telling you to restart, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Could try to contact Niantic, I guess. But there's nothing *we* can do.

Comment: Do you know how to contact Niantic

Comment: @FelipeValencia See the answer in this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273370/is-it-possible-to-log-back-into-a-pokemon-go-account

Comment: Tried it already