# Why can't I log back in to my Training Club Account on Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was on level 8 in the Training Club. I couldn't get in all day, so I tried to see if I could get in with a Google login instead. The Google login was up in no time but wants me to start over so I didn't pick a Pokémon and just closed that down.

I am still trying to get into my original training club where I was at level 8.  When I login online to the training club it says I have no Pokémon, as if my entire account is wiped out. How can I get my progress back?

Comment: NLock, What site are you using to see your Pokemon GO account on the Web?

Answer (score 2):

I have a [similar problem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276043/how-to-retrieve-a-pok%C3%A9mon-go-account-when-you-log-in-and-it-tells-you-to-start-a), in my case it is my gmail account and I was level 10 in-game.

According to an article on [Polygon](http://www.polygon.com/2016/7/12/12167482/pokemon-go-update-ios-trainer-club-account-issue), the 1.0.1 update to Pokemon Go for iOS is to blame for locking people out of their Trainer Club accounts:

> Pokémon Go is reportedly locking users out of their Pokémon Trainer Club accounts, following an update for iOS users. According to members of Reddit, along with those of us at Polygon, the latest version of the game is locking out players who use their Trainer Club logins to access the game.

To fix your issue, you should update Pokemon Go to version 1.0.2:

> **Update:** Niantic Labs has released an update for Pokémon Go on iOS that fixes the Trainer Club login issue. Version 1.0.2 is now available to download and will allow players with Trainer Club accounts to log back into their accounts.