# Order of defending Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-go

When you put a Pokemon to defend a Gym, it places depending on its CP but if two pokemon have the same CP where is it placed? Chronologically? Alphabetically? and if so, ascending or descending?

Comment: In my own experience it usually then relates to the HP of the pokemon, the one with the higher HP being the one on the higher level.

Comment: @daniel, i dont get what you say about " being the one on the higher level". hypothetically are both the same level.

Comment: I meant higher level in terms of positioning in the gym so the lower level ( being the one with the lowest CP) is the pokemon you battle first. The top level being the one you battle last. If one CP is equal to another (probably a rare case but I have seen it at the gym close to where I work) then the one with the higher HP will be on the higher level.

Comment: aahh ok. im not sure right now (and cant check). is the hp revealed while checking a gym?

Comment: Not as far as I know, but I do know it can't be alphabetical as the pokemon on top was a Machoke and second an Exeggutor. both with 780 CP but characteristically the Machoke would have the higher HP. I could be wrong... but that is how I see it when the neighboring office keeps stealing the gym from me xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ordered by who has more HP which is health so this is what happens when a Pokémon has the same CP (combat Power)

Comment: same as Daniel commented before but thanks!

Comment: K jus that HP is health power not a higher level like explained it and if the answer helped put helpful on it please

Comment: yeah, we know what HP and CP stands for. and if i could i would put Daniel answer as the helpful one as he answer it before and more detailed one

Comment: K and do you have an answer for this question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276043/how-to-retrieve-a-pok%c3%a9mon-go-account-when-you-log-in-and-it-tells-you-to-start-a

Comment: are you saying that the link has an answer for this question or that if i have an answer for the question in the link? is weird linking a duplicated and non related question ...

Comment: read this, Felipe. http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9831/answering-a-question-using-someone-elses-comment/9832#9832

Comment: It's a non related question but I am asking if you know an answer for that question I have you a link to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42768/discussion-between-felipe-valencia-and-lois6b).

Comment: Comments are not for asking others to answer your question.  Please do not use it as such.

Comment: i completely forgot to validate your answer, sorry