# How do I log into Pokemon Go if my Gmail account was deactivated?

Tags: pokemon-go, technical-issues

I had created a Pokemon Go account using a school email account way back when the game came out and I didn't foresee that it would eventually be deleted. I am aware that you can swap emails if you use a real or dummy FaceBook account, but considering that I am currently unable to even log in, this isn't an option at this time. My problem--though honestly somewhat self-inflicted--is this: is there a way to get back into my account? I already contacted Niantic and am awaiting some form of a response to my request, but since it would seem their track record for responding isn't the greatest, I thought I'd pool my resources and see what I can do.

Comment: Please clarify whether it's the Pokemon Go account that you cannot access or your actual Gmail account was deactivated.

Some [redditors](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/8nhw7z/help_account_deleted/) found that they got their account back by trying to login multiple times. Maybe try that? Other than that I don't think there's many things that can be done on your end since it's not the client's fault. Also have a look at [this thread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/273374/158272).

Comment: The login validation fails because the Gmail account has been deactivated. I know the Gmail account no longer exists for a fact. I am trying to see if there is a way to regain access without this (which is unlikely but I thought I’d try).

Comment: Have you tried creating a new Gmail account under the same address as the deleted account? I have had my Gmail account deleted too but I couldn't create a new one with the same name, but it doesn't hurt to give it a try. Another option is to contact Google support through their [Google Drive online chat](https://support.google.com/drive/?hl=en&vid=0-563664815463-1532289442711#topic=14940&contact=1) (click on 'Other' and select 'Request chat'). If you ask about an issue with your Gmail, they will redirect you to the relevant chat and hopefully sort out the situation. Good luck!

Comment: The domain name belongs to my school district so there’s a very low chance of my being able to successfully duplicate it.

Comment: If you can contact the school district's email admin, ask about forwarding your old address so you may at least receive email.  Then you may be able to change/reset the login password.

Comment: @Jerry Even if I did know who that was—and I’m honestly surprised I don’t—we were warned well in advance to move anything over to new accounts. This was my SOLE outlier. Besides, with the way we have things set up, they’d have to create a new account with the same name. The one I used for this account has been deleted entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have already contacted them but your best action would be to wait to hear back from Niantic support and see if they are able to restore the account data to a new G-Mail or Pokemon Go account.

Your best bet would be to find any receipts of any in game purchases you made, through PayPal, bank card purchases etc as they will have a transaction ID that they may be able to link with your account.

Without this they have no way to confirm you are the original owner of the deleted G-Mail account and will probably not restore said account.

Answer (score 0):

Found it in the help section of Pokemon Go.
Link your account to a Facebook account.
Then log in to Pokemon Go using the Facebook account.
Unlink your google account.
Then you can link a new google account.

Comment: How can he link his FB account if he can't log in?

Answer (score -6):

im new at this but did you have your account synced to like a phone maybe as like a recovery number and how long has your account get been deleted for?
if it hasn't been deleted for long go here maybe it might help https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6236295?hl=en

Comment: Please read the question more thoroughly next time