# Can I log back into my Pokémon Go account if I'm told it doesn't exist?

Tags: pokemon-go

I normally use Facebook to sign into Pokémon Go. However as of today I couldn’t sign in and a pop up keeps saying that the account does not exist. So I tried going in as a new trainer with the same Facebook account in hopes to try switch back to the original account but failed to do so. Hence, now I’m stuck being a new trainer starting from scratch... any ways for me to switch back to my original trainer?

Comment: Hi Elaine, this is a tech support question, and we can't help you with account problems. I suggest looking [here](https://support.pokemon.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000646483--Unable-to-authenticate-or-Failed-to-log-in-error-when-logging-in-to-Pok%C3%A9mon-GO) first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about account support.

Comment: I'm not really sure which part of this is off-topic, considering we have [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273370/is-it-possible-to-log-back-into-a-pokemon-go-account) and many, many duplicates.